# Cant play your video file- When playing youtube video on windows phone

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8, youtube

I am unable to play you tube videos by launching media player..Other remote videos work fine, only those from you tube don't work

```
 public play()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.MediaPlayerLauncher();
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klrOe7MelHA", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
        }
```

A message is displayed saying cant play your file.